# Android Testing: Dialog. Check it isShowing()

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, reflection, dialog

Here is my method, it works fine and shows the Dialog.

```
public void showDialog(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
    dialog.show();
}
```

I have a test project and I would like to test that the Dialog is showing up. I would like to apply the .isShowing() method. Something like this...

```
assertTrue(dialog.isShowing());
```

But I don't know how to get to the dialog variable within my test.

I am not using Robotium (this isn't an option for me).
I'm currently using the ActivityUnitTestCase to test with. If any more information is required please don't hesitate to ask.

**EDIT**

I have attempted to use the answer below by making the Dialog public

```
public Dialog getDiag(){
    return dialog;
}
```

Using this answer: I have a new problem when I run showDialog() in the test, it breaks when it hits: dialog.show();

android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: * Unable to add window -- token null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare Dialog outside showDialog function and then implement a method which returns this Dialog instance.

```
public Dialog getDiag(){
    return dialog;
}
```

and then do something like this

```
assertTrue(new YourClassName().getDialog().isShowing());
```

Comment: Thank you I have changed my method to return the Dialog, I can then at least access the Dialog in my test. But I cannot call the Dialog.show() therefore I have taken that out of my method and I will call the show() after the Dialog is returned (in the activity).